# JQuery how to id of the button that called the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sender

I have a button `<button onclick="takedown()">` that when it is clicked JQuery will create a new button with the id of the text in a input and button, when that button is clicked it will call a function `deltebutton()` which should delete the button, but I need for JQuery to get the id of the button which called the function and set it to a String called id.

I tryed `$(event.target).attr('id');` and `$(this).attr('id');` but both of them did not work 
I goggled it but could not find anything.

This is the functions

```
    function takedown(){

note = document.getElementById("noteinput").value;

idh1 = note + "h1";
idbutton = note + "button";
idcenter = note + "center";

$('<center id="' +idcenter + '"> <h1 idh1="' + idh1 + '">' + note + '</h1> <button id="'+ idbutton +'" onclick="deletenote()"> Delete </button> </center>').appendTo("body");


}
```

and

```
function deletenote(){

    String id = $(event.target).attr('id');

    $(id).remove();

}
```

If anybody knows how to do this, it will be very helpful.

Comment: how is the original click function called?

Comment: @RobertSadler the original click function is called <button onclick="takedown()">

Comment: Post your entire takedown function and deletebutton functions so I can see what youre doing and where. Its hard to know what $(this) is based off one line of code

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you bothering with `document.getElementById` if you're using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use String in JS and jQuery. And your selector is wrong.

```
function deletenote(){
    var id = event.target.id;
    $('#'+id).remove();
}
```

Also I think you can just call remove without getting the ID.

```
function deletenote(){
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: I tried both of them but when I click the delete button it is still there

Comment: Try your event.target selector. `var id = $(event.target).attr('id');` Ive never used it so im not positive it will work

Comment: @Programer Take a look at my edit for the first function. Im still convinced the second should work

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution building on the previous answer and comments would be:

```
function deletenote(){
   $(event.target).remove();
}
```